# How to analyze data from a 2x3 experiment where one cell is missing?

Tags: statistical-significance, experiment-design

I have an experiment with two factors. The first factor, picture, has three levels: nice, ugly, absent (i.e., the picture is not presented). The second factor, information, has two levels: present, absent. The dependent variable is a continuous variable: liking.

Now, I did not run the picture=absent + information=absent condition because it would mean not presenting anything and asking people how much they liked it, which doesn't make a lot of sense. So I'm left with 5 cells instead of 6. Any ideas on how to analyse these data?

Comment: You could still estimate a main effects model (i.e. if you assume no interaction). You'd have 4 parameters (intercept, information and 2 for picture) and 5 cell-means. Presumably you have replications as well, in which case you could even model all 5 cells by including one interaction term, but that would probably be a little odd; unless you have a strong reason to fit it, it might be better to look on using that as a model-check.

Comment: Of course, as with any statistical modelling, any informative theory should guide your analysis choices - if you think there should be interaction, the main effects model may not make sense. In part it depends on the questions you want to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got five cells so there's no impediment to fitting a linear model with up to five parameters (including the intercept). You could just pick one cell as a reference & have one parameter for each other one, or use a scheme like the following if you want to interpret the model in terms of main effects & interactions ($x$'s are dummy predictors; $\bar{y}$'s, cell means for liking; $\beta$'s, coefficients):

$$\begin{array}{cccccccl}
\mathrm{picture} & \mathrm{info.} & (1) & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_1x_2 &\operatorname{E}\bar{y}\\
\mathrm{nice} & \mathrm{present} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \beta_0 + \beta_1 + \beta_2+\beta_{12}\\
\mathrm{ugly} & \mathrm{present} & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \beta_0 + \beta_1 +\beta_3\\
\mathrm{absent} & \mathrm{present} & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \beta_0 + \beta_1\\
\mathrm{nice} & \mathrm{absent} & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \beta_0 + \beta_2\\
\mathrm{ugly} & \mathrm{absent} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \beta_0 + \beta_3\\
\end{array}$$

If you just want main effects it could be like this:

$$\begin{array}{ccccccl}
\mathrm{picture} & \mathrm{info.} & (1) & x_1 & x_2 & x_3  &\operatorname{E}\bar{y}\\
\mathrm{nice} & \mathrm{present} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &  \beta_0 + \beta_1 + \beta_2\\
\mathrm{ugly} & \mathrm{present} & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  \beta_0 + \beta_1 +\beta_3\\
\mathrm{absent} & \mathrm{present} & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0  & \beta_0 + \beta_1\\
\mathrm{nice} & \mathrm{absent} & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  \beta_0 + \beta_2\\
\mathrm{ugly} & \mathrm{absent} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \beta_0 + \beta_3\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: thanks for the replies! The coding scheme looks interesting. Any suggestions on how to specify such a model in R?

Comment: `lm(liking~picture*info)` or `lm(liking~picture+info)` for models with & without interactions respectively.